# Netbeans no muestra los primeros caracteres de la tabla ASCII. Java

Tags: java, netbeans, ascii

> ☺☻♥♦♣♠•◘○◙♂♀♪♫☼►◄↕‼¶§▬↨↑↓→←∟↔☻↔▲▼ !""#$%&''())*+,-./01234568

Cuando imprimo los primeros caracteres en Netbeans hasta `!` me sale una caja vacía, intente cambiar en propiedades del proyecto el encoding de UTF-8 a ISO-8859-1 y nada, no hay manera.

¿alguien tiene alguna solución?

Comment: Bienvenida a Stackoverflow. Es necesario que muestres el código con el que estás trabajando, de lo contrario nadie podrá darte una solución. Por favor, [edita la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/138405/edit) poniendo el código que produce ese resultado. Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

No es un tema de Netbeans o de Java. Puedes comprobar [en la Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) que:

> El código ASCII reserva los primeros 32 códigos (numerados del 0 al 31
>   en decimal) para caracteres de control: códigos no pensados
>   originalmente para representar información imprimible, sino para
>   controlar dispositivos (como impresoras) que usaban ASCII. Por
>   ejemplo, el carácter 10 representa la función "nueva línea" (line
>   feed), que hace que una impresora avance el papel, y el carácter 27
>   representa la tecla "escape" que a menudo se encuentra en la esquina
>   superior izquierda de los teclados comunes.

Y el 32 sí te lo muestra, lo que pasa es que es el espacio.
El 33 es el primero visible (considerando el espacio como "no visible") y es el signo de exclamación `!`

En realidad, como se puede comprobar con las caracteres de tu pregunta, si tienes la fuente (tipo de letra) compatible, sí se muestran esos caracteres, pero en una consola o terminal del sistema no se suelen mostrar: [image: ascii en la web]

Pero incluso para mostrarlo aquí, el navegador usa otros códigos: el corazón es el código 9829 (2665 en hexadecimal):

```js
console.log("\u2665\u2666\u2667\u2664");
```

Comment: La cuestión es que al resto de compañeros de mi clase se les ve perfectamente, estamos tratando de representar los palos de una baraja francesa usando los símbolos ♥♦♣♠ y es mi caso el único en el que no puedo ver los códigos.

Comment: Es posible que tengan otras fuentes tipográficas o que usen otros [códigos para obtener esos iconos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playing_cards_in_Unicode):

Comment: En cualquier caso deberías añadir tu código en la pregunta, como ha comentado @A.Cedano, si quieres profundizar más en la solución a tu problema

Comment: Ya he editado la pregunta en el título. ¡Muchas gracias de todas formas!